# Swift classes and variable are not alloc and visible from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, signalr

I tried to use Swift version 4.2 and 5.0 and I had same result. Xcode says that errors when Swift objects init and use from Objective-C code.
Library SwiftR is up to date. Use Xcode 11.5

```
@import SwiftR;

@interface CHSignalrService ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) SignalR *srConnection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Hub * chatHub;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Hub * orderHub;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Hub * onlineInterpreterHub;

@end

@implementation CHSignalrService

#pragma makr - Lifecycle

- (void)startConnectionWithAccessToken:(NSString *)at {
    if (self.srConnection != nil) {
        return;
    }
//below is error: No visible @interface for 'SignalR' declares the selector 'init:connectionType:'
    self.srConnection = [[SignalR alloc] init:kSignalRBaseURLString connectionType:ConnectionTypeHub];
    NSMutableDictionary *headersDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"Authorization":at, @"Content-Type":@"application/json"}];
//below is error: Property 'headers' not found on object of type 'SignalR *'
    self.srConnection.headers = headersDict;
//below is error: No visible @interface for 'Hub' declares the selector 'init:'
    self.onlineInterpreterHub = [[Hub alloc] init:@"OnlineInterpreterHub"];
    [self.onlineInterpreterHub on:@"interpreterConnected" callback:^(NSArray * array) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kOnlineInterpreterNotification object:array];
    }];
    self.chatHub = [[Hub alloc] init:@"ChatHub"];
    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    [self.chatHub on:@"NobodyAnswered" callback:^(NSArray * array) {
        [weakSelf NobodyAnswered:nil];
    }];
}
```

Comment: [`SignalR`](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR) is not a `NSObject` subclass. That library is not Objective-C compatible.

Comment: Actually [it is](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/blob/3e06faae6f9c4cc3a4b7cbec9ac270f00ec32f0b/SwiftR/SwiftR.swift#L76) a `NSObject` subclass, but [it's missing](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/blob/3e06faae6f9c4cc3a4b7cbec9ac270f00ec32f0b/SwiftR/SwiftR.swift#L139) stuff like `@objc(initWithBaseUrl:connectionType:)`, ... The second part about the Obj-C compatibility is correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@objc` declaration before `SignalR` class declaration.
For reference - https://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Something like this :

```
@objc
open class SignalR: NSObject, SwiftRWebDelegate {
    static var connections = [SignalR]()
```

I hope this works for you.

Earlier there was no `@objc` declaration :
[image]

Thanks :)